# Evaluating variable contain mathematical expression in f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, expression-evaluation, f-string

I have to accept input (using `raw_input()`) as a power expression like `10**5` and then print its value. I have tried a few pieces of code but these do not give desired results:

```
print(f'{2**4}') #<-- prints 16 correctly
a = '{2**4}'
print(f'{{}}'.format(a)) #<-- prints {2**4}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like:

```
var = '2**4'
print(f'{<some way to expand var in here>}') #<-- prints 16
```

Comment: Does `eval` help?

Comment: Yes @Megalng - thanks

Comment: Depending on your needs `a = 2**4` could help, if `eval()` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In f-strings expressions are parsed with the equivalent of:

```
ast.parse('(' + expression + ')', '<fstring>', 'eval')
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse

But variables will be replaced with their actual value. What are you looking for is sort of a nested evaluation which is not supported by f-strings. Instead as a safe approach you can first split with '**' then covert to int and finally use power:

```
In [9]: s = "2**4"

In [10]: print(f"{pow(*map(int, s.split('**')))}")
16
```

Comment: It does in this case yes, but in case of other operators or expression chains it won't e.g. `print(f'{2**4}') 
a = '((2+4-10+88*2)/100)**5' 
print(eval ('f"{'+a+'}"'))`

Comment: @BabyGroot In that case take a look at answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Yes but most solutions require importing some module - `eval` and `extrapolation` is built into python - thanks anyways (+1)

Comment: @BabyGroot As it's also mentioned in many of those answers don't use `eval` on user input data. NEVER!

Comment: Yes i saw that - that's why i was wondering if we could just `int(<expr>)` with builtin support

Answer (score 1):

So this works for all expressions (e.g. `((2+4-10+88*2)/100)**5`) but I am not sure if this is the right way to go (since `eval` is not recommended)

```
a = '2**4'
print(eval (a))  #<-- prints 16
```